# Issue with summing arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to turn MySQL data into an array and then calculate the sum of that array.

```
$weight = ($product['av_id_1'])*$val; // get attribute values
$weightsub = explode(" ", $weight); // convert string to array
echo array_sum($weightsub);
```

I'm getting an output but its not what I expected, instead of a single integer its spaced integers like "30 40 50".

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: whats the value of $product['av_id_1'] ?

Comment: You are multiplying `$product['av_id_1']` with `$val`. I therefore find it highly unlikely that the result `$weight` (either an `int` or `float`) has spaces in it that you can `explode()` it by.

Comment: To add to that, after reading your question more carefully, I think you have a misunderstanding of how you can multiply array values. If `$product['av_id_1']` is supposed to represent an array: you cannot multiply all array element values in one go like that. If it's a supposed to represent a string of space separated integers: you cannot multiply their values like that either.

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example. Provide the values of `$product['av_id_1']` and `$val` by using [var_export](http://php.net/var-export), which will give you valid PHP code that represents your variables. That way we can reproduce your issue and help you debug it. @fireeyedboy is right, though $weight will always be a number when you conduct a multiplication operation on those two operands, the result must be a number type. So it makes no sense to me how you got a string back from array_sum that reads "30 40 50"

Comment: The output of $product['av_id_1'] returned by var_export was '3'  '2'

Comment: And the output of $val was 1 1...there was no need to multiply by val.

Answer (score 0):

```
$weightsub = explode(" ", $product['av_id_1']); // convert string to array
echo array_sum($weightsub)*$val;
```

First you need to extract all numbers using `explode`. Then apply `array_sum` to sum all numbers in the array, and multiply the sum by `$val`.

If this doesn't work as intended, you can easily do some basic debugging by using `echo` and `print_r` on each variable or result:

```
echo '$product[av_id_1] = <br>';
print_r($product['av_id_1']);
$weightsub = explode(" ", $product['av_id_1']); // convert string to array
echo '$weightsub = <br>';
print_r($weightsub);
echo "<br>\$val = $val<br>";
echo 'Sum = ' . array_sum($weightsub) . '<br>';
echo array_sum($weightsub)*$val;
```

Comment: Still not working unfortunately. Your code is outputting the same values as mine.

Comment: What is the output of `echo print_r($product['av_id_1']);`?

Comment: Try the second version of the script in my updated answer. It may help you locate where the problem is.

Comment: $weightsub = 
Array ( [0] => 3 ) 
$val = 1
Sum = 3
3  $weightsub = 
Array ( [0] => 2 ) 
$val = 1
Sum = 2
2  $weightsub = 
Array ( [0] => 6 ) 
$val = 1
Sum = 6
6  $weightsub = 
Array ( [0] => 4 ) 
$val = 1
Sum = 4
4  $weightsub = 
Array ( [0] => 5 ) 
$val = 1
Sum = 5
5

Comment: Thanks, still not understanding what the problem is though.

Comment: Based on the output you posted, your code is currently running in a loop. `$product['av_id_1']` only contains one number, so `explode` returns each time an array with only one element. You probably need to store each value of `$product['av_id_1']` within the loop. Then put the code I posted after the loop. It is difficult to tell more since I don't know what is happening before and after the code you posted.

Comment: I'll edit my question to contain the full code. $product['av_id_1'] definitely contains more than one number as my original output shows. It is supposed to contain variables for weights of items in a shopping cart.